# Video app doesn't work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

I just started using Windows 8 today and it seems I've already managed to mess it up. The video app doesn't work when I launch it. It opens and closes after about 1 sec and returns to the start screen. This also happens to a couple of games I installed. Googling it, I found that many others have been having the same problem but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Which video apps are not running peoperly? I have handbrak and freemake video converter which works pretty well.

Comment: I'm talking about the inbuilt video app on the metro interface.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: This behavior can be explained by using the default Administrator account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Windows 10. It has been patched since.